# Generate n integers in range[min, max] whose sums is m

Tags: algorithm

im trying to build a grid of blocks, each block have a random size, people call it masonry, I think the key is creating a list of integer(which represents how many unit need to build it up), anyway, let focus in the question which I 've written above
Here is my backtracking algorithm(I don't know exactly what type of this, I just go to my editor and write it, then i call it backtracking :D).
The problem is when i increase m(sum) to about thousands, it gets slow and throw Max callstack depth. Anyone helps me solve this problem, or optimize it.
Apologize my English

```js
/**
  *  backtracking generating
  */
function generateSums(init:number[] = [], n: number, m: number, min: number, max: number):number[] {
  //console.log(init, n, m);
  if (!n) {
    if (!m) return init;
    const lastEl = init.pop() || 0;
    return generateSums(init, n + 1, m + lastEl, min, max);
  }
  const div = m / n;
  if (div < min) {
    //console.log('lt', div, min);
    if (!init.length) throw("CANNOT GENERATE");
    const lastEl = init.pop() || 0;
    return generateSums(init, n+1, m + lastEl, min, max);
  }
  if (div > max) {
    //console.log('gt', div, max);
    if (!init.length) throw("CANNOT GENERATE");
    const lastEl = init.pop() || 0;
    return generateSums(init, n + 1, m + lastEl, min, max);
  }
  if (n === 1) {
    if (m >= min && m <=max) return [...init, m];
  }
  const gen = randRange(min, max);
  const out = [...init, gen];
  return generateSums(out, n - 1, m - gen, min, max);
}
```